# How can I give parameter to redirected index page in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, get, header

I have a problem with parameter and GET method.
I have index.php as following downside:

```
include 'head.php';
$page=$_GET['page'];
switch($page)
{
case main:
   include'main.php';
   break;
case page1:
   include 'page1.php';
   break;
case page2:
    include 'page3.php'
   break;
}
```

I want to give parameter in a form or with header
I tried in Page 2 but it doesn't work

```
<form action:"?page=page1?parameter=1">
```

I also tried with header like

```
header('Location:http:myurl/?page=page1?parameter=1');
```

It also doesn't work
How can I give parameter to another page in this situation.
Best Regards..

Comment: why `action:` and not `action=`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I write in my localhost = I made a mistake carry to here sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing the format. For form should use `=` instead of `:` and for query string params should divided by `&` signs than `?`

```
<form action="?page=page1&parameter=1">
```

As for PHP using header function can try this

```
header('location: http://myurl/?page=page1&parameter=1');
```

Comment: I make this ```<form action="?page=page1" method="GET">``` my link view http://myurl/&parameter=1&parameter=2    but page1 is not redirected to url why it is?